# Object.observe - Multiple observers support?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, object.observe

Can someone tell me if `Object.observe()` will (once implemented) allow to register multiple observers via multiple calls? Or only the last one will stay?

For example if I do:

```
Object.observe(obj, myFirstFunction);
Object.observe(obj, mySecondFunction);
```

Will both functions get called when my object is updated or only `mySecondFunction`?

Comment: The future is difficult to predict.

Comment: @Anko Yeah but maybe someone that has looked closely to the specs could bring some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and I got that both are being called.

```
var obj = {name:'MD'};
var myFirstFunction = function (changes) {
    console.log("First " ,Object.keys(changes[0]))
}
var mySecondFunction = function (changes) {
    console.log("Second ",Object.keys(changes[0]))
}

Object.observe(obj, myFirstFunction);
Object.observe(obj, mySecondFunction);

obj.name = "Mritunjay"
```

Comment: How did you tried ? I enabled Google Chrome's *Experimental JavaScript* flag but when I write `Object.observe` in my console it outputs `undefined`. I have Chrome 35 and according to [this](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/) table it should be available. Any clue ?

Comment: I tried it in normal chrome console, it was not working, then I tried with node. Same error in chrome. Trying

Comment: @Flawyte see [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/04/chrome-35-beta-more-developer-control.html) it says `Update April 29th: Object.observe has been pushed back to Chrome 36.`